# MySQL functional Data adding

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to MySQL and am using MySQL to work on a project based on an ordering system.

What's I have is a table for:

```
Session Table:
PK Session_ID
Date: Session_Date 

Delivery Table:
PK: Delivery_Type (eg. Firstclass, Secondclass)
Int: Delivery_TimeToDeliver (1, 2, 3, these represent the expected time to deliver)

Order Table: 
PK: Order_ID: autonum + 1
FK: Delivery Type
Date: Delivery_EstimatedTime
```

What I'd like to do with adding an order is to calculate the estimated time based on the session ID is essentially:

```
Delivery_EstimatedTime = (Session Date + Delivery_TimeToDeliver)
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Could I do it on record insert into?

Comment: whatr is the unit of Delivery_TimeToDeliver? days? weeks?

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
INSERT INTO Order(Delivery_Type, Delivery_EstimatedTime)
SELECT Delivery_Type, Session_Date + INTERVAL Delivery_TimeToDeliver DAY
FROM Session
LEFT JOIN Delivery ON (Delivery_Type = @Delivery_Type)
WHERE Session_ID = @Session_ID
```

where you put values for @Delivery_Type and @Session_ID

Comment: I've applied it to what I'm trying to do:

`INSERT INTO rbickers.order(Del_Type, Delivery_EstimatedTime)
SELECT Del_Type, Ses_Date + INTERVAL Del_TimeToDeliver DAY
FROM Session
LEFT JOIN rbickers.delivery ON (Del_Type = "Second Class")
WHERE Ses_ID = "1"`

But it's saying 'unknown column 'Del_Type' in field list.

Is that error something to do with the '"Second Class"' that I've put in quotes?

Comment: above you wrote 'Delivery_Type', now you tring to use the column rbickers.delivery.Del_Type, what is the name of the column?

Comment: It's Del_Type but the schema is rbickers and the table is delivery.

Comment: the error says your column isn't named Del_Type, the code should work, tried it on: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edd51/1/0